# How to install and start using nodeJS in brackets( or any other text editor)

Tags: node.js, text-editor, brackets

I'm a complete newbie and have been trying to use NodeJs for like two days now and nothing is working. If somebody could please explain to me step by step how to start using Node efficiently(Brackets preferred but any is welcome I'm so desperate right now:) If you use Node, please help me through installation and use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/brackets-nodejs-integration go through this link it might help you for bracket

Answer (score 0):

If you are new biee then you have to first download [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) Then create folder and make file with any name for ex. index.js and in index.js write `console.log('my first app');` Then open command line and write this command: `node index.js` and hit enter you will see my first app in cmd!

Comment: I have nodejs installed already and after doing what you suggested it says cannot find module c:\windows/systems32/index.js

Comment: @YousufDaramay Check your package.json file for entry point, whether it is app.js or index.js based on that you should run node app.js or node index.js

Answer (score 0):

1. Create file under "c:/Node/MyFirstApp/" called server.js
2. Write console.log('App started') in your server.js file
3. Start up the Node.js command prompt
4. Do cd c:/Node/MyFirstApp/
5. Do node server.js
6. Your server is running!